# AAPT err(): \src\main\res\drawable\asciisentence.png: libpng warning: bKGD: invalid

Tags: android, aapt

The error occouring is

```
AAPT err(): libpng error: Not a PNG file 
AAPT err(): \src\main\res\drawable\asciisentence.png: libpng warning: bKGD: invalid
```

I followed the steps to convert it to a proper image but I still get an error.

How do i sort this error out?

Comment: how did you convert it into png ?

Comment: @Shubhank The file was a png file, used Paint to properly convert it to png.

Comment: can you try any online editor like use http://imgur.com and upload your image and now download it from there. it should convert it into valid format

Comment: @Shubhank I downloaded the image from imgur.com . The error showing now is  AAPT err(Facade for 943727257): libpng error: Not a PNG file                Error:Execution failed for task '::mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Comment: @Shubhank I don't have access to mail it right now, thanks nevertheless!!

Comment: ok, try with some other image otherwise. Not sure of the error here.

Comment: @Shubhank that solved the problem! Thanks!!